# Whats happened to the battery? Help understanding the BAT0 report

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

my laptop's battery seems dead(the laptop only runs with the AC plugged in), but the BAT0 report says the following:

```
▶—— NOTEBOOK BATTERY (BAT0) ——◀

Complete Report:
 Name                     GC06066
 SBDS Manufacture Date         2010-10-16
 design capacity          5900 mAh
 last full capacity       5266 mAh
 design voltage           11100 mV
 design capacity warning  200 mAh
 design capacity low      70 mAh
 capacity granularity 1   100 mAh
 capacity granularity 2   100 mAh
 capacity state           ok
 charging state           charged
 present rate             0 mA
 remaining capacity       0 mAh
 present voltage          4205 mV
 AC-state                 on-line

Capacity Summary:
 Remaining capacity:      0 mAh, 0%
 Design capacity:         5900 mAh
 Last full capacity:      5266 mAh, 89.2% of design capacity
 Capacity loss:           10.8%
```

It says "capacity state: ok", "charging state: charged" but also Remaining capacity: 0mAh.

How do you interpret this? My guess would be that "present voltage          4205 mV" is just not enough, but at the same time the battery is not supposed to be "in use" as it seems to be charged and the laptop is at AC plug.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: 4V seems pretty low to me, since it's meant to be at 11V at full charge. It looks like you have a defective battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is dead most likely:

- remaining capacity of zero
- present voltage << design voltage

Imho the battery controller has shut down the battery irreversibly.

Try the following:

- Power off laptop and remove charger
- Remove battery briefly
- Connect charger and let charge over night